# storm failing to process all the tuples

Tags: real-time, apache-kafka, distributed-computing, apache-storm

I'm using Apache Storm to process huge data coming off a Kafka spout. Currently, there are over 3k json messages already published to Kafka and it's continuing. I have to process all the messages published from beginning. So, I have set a Kafka spout parameter accordingly.

This results in a lot of failures in tuple processing. I got this info from the storm UI.

I suspect the storm is not able to handle all the messages bombarded towards it in a single shot.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can set parameter `max.spout.pending` to apply backpres. Or you can increase message timeout (or disable it).

Comment: could you please provide more information regarding the error you are facing , processing 3K touple should never be a problem as such, unless your bolt is doing something very complex processing

Comment: can you post a screenshot of storm UI.

Comment: Do you use acking with storm? You should see in storm-ui if there are indeed failed tuples with acking enabled.

Comment: I managed to get away with the fails. I decreased the parallelism hint count given as a parameter in the setBolt method. I reduced it from 20s to 2 or 3 and it worked. Not sure why!

Answer (score 1):

1) increase the parallelism hint for the bolts so that there's no backlog slowing down the processing for any tuple emitted by the spout, or

2) use the topology.max.spout.pending property to limit the number of tuples the spout can emit before having to wait for one of those tuples to complete.

try combination of both solutions. In production usually you need to run many iterations to get proper value of both the values (parallelism,topology.max.spout.pending)